# Best practice for maintaining updated Git binaries (Git by Git) on Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: git, macos

On my Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) machine, I have installed Git 1.6.0.2 using the [git-OSX-Installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) from Google Code. The installer installs Git to /usr/local/Git.

I would now like to keep up with the latest stable Git release (Master branch), currently 1.6.0.3.

Can I run "git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git" from within the /usr/local/Git directory, then Configure/Make/Install using XCode, or will that not work?

Basically I'm looking for the best practice to keep Git updated to the latest stable version.

Comment: You can compile using the usual commands `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git && make && sudo make install`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The script [x-git-update-to-latest-version](http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2008/09/updated_xgitupd.html)  will compile and install the latest version of git (from the git repository).

It's set to use the current `HEAD` revision of the master branch, but it should be easy enough to add a line or two to `git checkout` the stable branch.

It installs git into `/usr/local/git-v1.6.0.2-287-g3791f77/` (for example), then symlinks /usr/local/git/ to the latest directory.

You can set it to run periodically (nightly?), either via cron (which is extremely simple, but has some irritating issues on OS X 10.5.x), or the slightly convoluted launchd ([Lingon](http://tuppis.com/lingon/) is a nice interface to this, although to start the job running without logging in/out, you have to run the command `launchctrl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/mylaunchagent.plist`)

Answer (score 6):

I keep Git up to date on my Mac using [MacPorts](http://macports.org). I find that there is a lot of other stuff in MacPorts that I need as well, so this works well for me.

Comment: MacPorts/Fink and the like aren't always completely up-to-date. As the questioner said, he wants to update to 1.6.0.3, but git-OSX-installer and MacPorts are all currently at 1.6.0.2. Rather trivial, however..

Comment: MacPorts is great. Agree with comment above though. They do tend to be a point release or two out from the latest. Usually not enough to cause a huge problem though.

Answer (score 1):

I pull the git source using:

```
git clone git://git2.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
```

and periodically do

```
cd ~/git.git
git pull
make
make test
sudo make install
```

That way I keep up to date, and I'm using git to get git, which just feels like the right thing to do.  I haven't yet gone as far as adding a cron entry to do this automatically.

(The first time I did this, of course, I downloaded the git source manually and built and installed it, to solve the obvious chicken-and-egg problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled git from source with no problems, as far as i can tell no port is required so just keep your version updated in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

I download the source and have a little script do the building and updating:

```
sudo git clean -dxf
git pull
make prefix=/usr/local/git all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local/git install
```

this cleans up files before setting the prefix to my build location (/usr/local/git)